# Cannot adjust brightness via Fn key

Tags: gnome

I just set up a new Arch with Gnome 3.2. Until now, everything seems to work fine, except for the brightness adjustment. When I try to adjust the brightness from within the Gnome settings or with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>☼↑</kbd>, the screen flickers for some seconds and afterwards the brightness stays the same (<kbd>Fn</kbd> variant) or has changed (Gnome settings). It seems like some other part of the system insists on keeping the brightness as is, there is a fight and this other part wins.

**edit**:

The Hardware is a Samsung N130 Netbook with an Intel 945GME graphics controller.

**update**: The culprit of this manifests itself as this line in `/var/log/messages`:

```
samsung_laptop: SABI set command 0x01 failed with completion flag 0xaa and data 0xff
```

Some research led to [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=737108), which says that a patch for the problem is on its way into the 3.2 kernel.

Comment: Did you see anything from kernel output ( /var/log/messages for example ) ? Have you tried to load kernel modules like thinkpad_acpi for Thinkpads ?

Comment: Select 'System Default' instead of 'gnome' in login screen when you login

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following, this might bring you luck.

1. Open your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. `sudo vi /etc/default/acpi_support`
3. Find and enable this line (remove the # behind):

   `ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE=true`
4. Install the laptop mode tool from [Laptop Mode](http://samwel.tk/laptop_mode/packages)
5. `sudo vi /etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf`

```
# Enable laptop mode when on AC power.
ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_AC=1
# Should laptop mode tools control LCD brightness?
CONTROL_BRIGHTNESS=1
# Commands to execute to set the brightness on your LCD
BATT_BRIGHTNESS_COMMAND="echo 0"
LM_AC_BRIGHTNESS_COMMAND="echo 9"
NOLM_AC_BRIGHTNESS_COMMAND="echo 9"
BRIGHTNESS_OUTPUT=”/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video1/brightness”
```

---

You can read the instructions before editing the file:

```
＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊
# * If your system has the file “/proc/acpi/video/VID/LCD/brightness” (VID may
# be VID1 or similar), use this file as BRIGHTNESS_OUTPUT, and use
# the command “echo “. The possible values can be listed using the
# command
#
# cat /proc/acpi/video/VID/LCD/brightness
# * If you have a file /sys/class/backlight/…/brightness, then you can use
# that file as BRIGHTNESS_OUTPUT, and the command “echo “.
#
# As far as I understand it the values are between 0 and
# the value contained in the file /sys/class/backlight/…/max_brightness.
＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem with my Dell Laptop running Xubuntu.  The solution offered by Blue Sky hasn't worked for me, but I was able to set up a script (to be run thru sudo).

```
cd /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
cat max_brightness > brightness
```

There is also a `/sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight` directory, but that didn't seem to work on my system.

Answer (score 0):

After hacking around for hours and getting to various states of half-working brightness up/down `Fn keys` I ended up installing `samsung-tools` - [this guide worked for me](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/app/samsung-tools/) nicely.

I was able by pressing `Fn keys` to decrease brightness only. But using terminal I was able to adjust brightness normally - increase/decrease.

*Samsung np300v5z, Ubuntu 12.04.*